# What type of data can we get from fMRI to calculate correlations?

Tags: fmri, data, correlation

Lets say we want to compare the correlation between the activation one part of the brain and rise in value of other variable. The design would be within subjects.

What is the data that we can receive from the fMRI from one specific brain area(e.g. temporal cortex) to use to calculate the correlation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BOLD response is used in fMRI to provide a quantified measure of activation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemodynamic_response. It is based on the ratio of oxygenated vs. non-oxygenated blood, implying blood flow, and inferred to mean more processing or activation of those brain areas.

Comment: Thank you. What is the smallest "amount" of brain you can receive this data from?

Comment: Spatial resolution in voxels depends on the strength of the MRI magnet. A typical 3T magnet might provide resolution down to a few millimeters, depending on the methods used. More detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_magnetic_resonance_imaging#Spatial_resolution